# For multiple answer question, should I accept an answer, or should I let it run wild?

Tags: discussion

Sometime ago, I posted [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5305/seminal-papers-that-later-were-proven-to-contain-errors) on the economics.stack and now I don't know how to proceed. Should I accept an answer, or should I let it be free?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, if there's an answer that was most helpful and "settled the debate" for you, you should accept that.

I like that specific question a lot, and I'm a bit worried that accepting an answer might deter people from posting more answers. In that respect, I'd suggest you to not accept an answer - but of course, you're free to do either way.

Comment: I agree. This specific question is very open-ended so there will never be a final *correct* or *best* answer. It is therefore hard to know which criteria one should use if the policy were to accept an answer on such questions.

Comment: Ok, I let it run wild. :)